# What is the right way to stop the first path from painting before transition is applied?

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 line chart with one line being added at load time and two lines being added dynamically after a user presses a button. The second line should transition from the original line and the third line should transition from the position of the second line's finished transition. I have got it partially working but the final line is painted in position before the transition occurs and then is removed when the transition starts , which looks weird. How do I amend the code so that this final transition line does not paint before the transition takes place. The original line:

```
function drawAD(){

//setup  original line
var aggregateDemandLine = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i){return xScale(ADX[i])})
.y(function(d,i){return yScale(ADY[i])})

g.append("path")
.attr("class","AD1")
.attr("fill","none")
.attr("stroke","green")
.attr("stroke-width","3px")
.attr("d",aggregateDemandLine(ADX))
}
```

Below is the function to add the second and third lines with transitions.

```
function accelerate(){
 var initial, accelerated;

var initialAD = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i){return xScale(ADX[i])})
.y(function(d,i){return yScale(initialADMoveY[i])})

g.append("path").attr("class","first").attr("d", function(){

initial = initialAD(ADX);
return initial;
}).attr("stroke","green")
.attr("stroke-width",3)
.attr("pointer-events","none")
.attr("class","first")

var acceleratedAD = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i){return xScale(ADX[i])})
.y(function(d,i){return yScale(acceleratedADY[i])})

g.append("path").attr("class","second").attr("d", function(){
accelerated = acceleratedAD(ADX)
return accelerated;
})
.attr("stroke","green")
.attr("stroke- width",3).attr("pointer-events","none")
.attr("class","second");

d3.select('.first')
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attrTween('d', function (d) {

return d3.interpolateString(ADPath, initial);
}).on("end",secondTransition);

function secondTransition(){
 d3.select('.second')
 .transition()
 .duration(2000)
 .attrTween('d', function (d) {

 return d3.interpolateString(initial, accelerated);
 });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function   accelerate(){
var initial, accelerated;

var initialAD = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i){return xScale(ADX[i])})
.y(function(d,i){return yScale(initialADMoveY[i])})

 //create the initial path
 var initial = initialAD(ADX);

 var acceleratedAD = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i){return xScale(ADX[i])})
.y(function(d,i){return yScale(acceleratedADY[i])})

 //create accelerated
var accelerated = acceleratedAD(ADX);

g.append("path").attr("class","first").attr("d",ADPath)
.attr("stroke-width",3)
.attr("stroke","green")
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attrTween("d" ,function(){
  return d3.interpolateString(ADPath,initial)
 }).on("end",secondTransition)


function secondTransition(){
g.append("path").attr("class","second").attr("d",initial)
.attr("stroke-width",3)
.attr("stroke","green")
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attrTween('d', function (d) {
 return d3.interpolateString(initial, accelerated);
});
}
```